# SQL Server, replace value of column A with value of column B, and value of column B with value of column A

Tags: sql, sql-server

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYFSs.png)

I need help to reverse value of column (seconddescription) to the value of column (longdescription) 
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: kindly give us a sample result

Comment: Update Products
SET 
 seconddescription = longdescription,
 longdescription = seconddescription
WHERE upc = '0480901015202'

Comment: so you mean you want to swap the column names, isn't?

Comment: If you're actually using SQL Server (and not MySQL) you can simply run this update as-is :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE whatever_your_table_is_called
SET    seconddescription = longdescription
      ,longdescription = seconddescription
```

Answer (score 0):

cant test this right now but you could make a new column (col3) then
UPDATE table set col3=col1, col1=col2, col2=col3

and then delete col3

Comment: This is only needed in MySQL, every other DBMS can simply swap both columns :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try Below:

```
UPDATE ABC SET longdescription = seconddescription, seconddescription = longdescription;
```

Here, ABC is your table name.